# Parsing arbitrary Ruby code to create a list arguments passed to all invocations of a particular method

Tags: ruby, parsing, metaprogramming

I have an inherited codebase analogous to the following trivial example:

`request_handling_helper_methods.rb`

```
def send_response(response_code)
  # create and post a response using response_code
  true
end

def handle_common_domain_errors(request)
  return send_response('E22') if request.contains('foo')
  # other checks that send different responses
  nil
end

def handle_unrelated_thing(request)
  return send_response('E777') if request.green?
end
```

`handle_request.rb`

```
require 'request_handling_helper_methods.rb'

def handle_request_type_1(request)
  return send_response('E1200') if request.not_type_1?

  return send_response('E88') if Date.today.is_tuesday?
  
  raise if handle_common_domain_errors(request)

  send_response('I100')
end
```

`maintainance_scripts/response_code_analysis.rb`

```
def all_response_codes_for_request(type)
  # ***THIS IS WHAT I AM UNSURE OF HOW TO POPULATE***
  # parse handle_request_type_#{type}
  # and return a list of all possible response codes
end
```

I'm expecting `all_response_codes_for_request` to parse the code inside handle_request_type_1 and pull out the argument passed in for all method calls to `send_response`.

Expected output of method `all_response_codes_for_request(1)` is `['E22', 'E1200', 'E88', 'I100']`. Note that 'E777' should not be in the list because the method `handle_unrelated_thing`is not called within`handle_request_type_1` method.

If I was starting from scratch, knowing the requirement of listing all possible codes for each request type from the start, I would consider creating a YAML/JSON file with some request types, method names and response codes in, but this is an inherited codebase, containing over 200 request types and probably 5,000 or more codes (with new request types and codes being added regularly), I'd like to parse the code/conduct static analysis to work out all possible codes.

The calls to `send_response` are nested arbitrarily deep within other methods, across a number of files.

I'm aware of a gem named 'ruby2ruby' that can parse ruby code, but whether that is part of a solution to this problem, I'm not sure.

Comment: This will be a tough row to hoe. Besides the chunk of functionality hanging off of request you also have decision points based on the **contents** of the request. If **everything** is based off `send_response` w/ possible conditionals after you may be able to use that to at least gather a list of those conditions, but... yay fun.

Comment: Honestly it might be easier to just do it manually or use the test suite.

Comment: Because surely there's a test suite.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. There are a few tests, but sadly not for all cases for all requests! 

Hoping somebody has an answer, but at least expanding the test coverage would at least kill 2 birds with one stone.

Comment: Oh no....Well a functional but dirty solution would be to glob all the files, then read each line for each file and pull the codes e.g. `Dir.glob('path/**/*.rb').flat_map {|f| File.foreach(f).filter_map {|line| line.match(/send_response[\s\(]+?['"](.*?)['"]/)&.captures}}` might work? to get all the codes; however lining this up with the method definition is going to be tricky.

Comment: Thanks, @engineersmnky. Given there isn't a plausible completely automated solution, at least getting all possible response codes might minimise the amount of manual work involved.